# warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'lrint'

Tags: c, opencv

I want to compile an opencv program on the Linux machine below:

```
sav@machine:/shared/sav/test$ uname -a
Linux machine 2.6.32-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 16 14:58:24 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My gcc command is the following:

```
gcc -I/shared/sav/opt/include -L/shared/sav/opt/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lm imagefilter.c -o imagefilter
```

After I run the program, I have the following warning:

```
In file included from /shared/sav/opt/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h:47,
from /shared/sav/opt/include/opencv/cv.h:63,
from imagefilter.c:1:
/shared/sav/opt/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h: In function 'cvRound':
/shared/sav/opt/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h:327: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'lrint'
```

How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly make sure that you have included the header `math.h` in your program.
2. Use this `-std=c99` option along with `gcc` to resolve this compiler issue.

Change

```
gcc -I/shared/sav/opt/include -L/shared/sav/opt/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lm imagefilter.c -o imagefilter
```

to

```
gcc -std=c99 -I/shared/sav/opt/include -L/shared/sav/opt/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lm imagefilter.c -o imagefilter
```

Refer this for more info on usage of [lrint](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lrint.3.html)

Comment: Ok, now the warning disappeared. Can you explain me quickly what was the problem?

Comment: From the man page as mentioned in the answer, `-std=c99` option is necessary as this glibc feature is supported only after `c99`

Answer (score 0):

Include the below header file (math.h).Usually this warnings are because of not including the header file where the function is defined.

```
#include <math.h>
```

Comment: Done but the problem is still there.